# how to configure HttpServletRequest in application context file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am unable to configure `HttpServletRequest` in application context in my spring environment.

below is the code I tried:

```
<bean id="request" class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest">
 </bean>

<bean id="rwEloquaControllerService" class="com.rightwave.eloqua.RWEloquaControllerService">  
<property name="request" ref="request" />
</bean>
```

`RWEloquaControllerService` class code for getter setter:

```
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
```

But when I start my server, exceptions occurred due to application context error. can any one tell me how to configure `HttpServletRequest` object in application context.

Comment: `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` is an interface. Why would you try to instantiate it, by the way ?

Comment: @Berger, I need the request object in my service class. Can I not instantiate an interface in application context. Basically, I need request object to get context, then springContext and then get a bean. So at first point I need request.

Comment: Why would you need nor want your request tin the service class. You don't want your service layer to depend on the web layer. Also injecting something like that is a bad thing imho, if you really really really must pass it in as a method argument and pass if from the controller to the service...

Comment: You shouldn't get a bean, using the request. Just inject the bean...

Comment: @JSK No, you can't instantiate an interface, but you can instantiate an object that has this interface. For this way you need to configure a class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about some basic concepts first.

1. In my Knowledge, it's not possible to instantiate an interface in application context. How do you new an interface without give it real implementation? It's impossible.
2. You write bean in application context so that Spring can instantiate them. However, the request you want is generated by servlet container. It's not created by Spring.

If you want to inject request in your controller, just add the following code in your controller. Spring doesn't create the request, Spring just get it from servlet container then inject it into the controller.

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> Can I not instantiate an interface in application context. Basically, I need request object to get context, then springContext and then get a bean. So at first point I need request

Simply make you controller implement `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware`. You will have to add the `public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException` method, which you can use to set the provided `applicationContext` to a member variable.

You can then use it to query the context for spring-managed beans.

Note: the `setApplicationContext` method will be invoked by Spring after your controller has been created but before `afterPropertiesSet` is invoked (if you implement `InitializingBean`).